# Permissions are ignored when running unit tests from ant with fork enabled

Tags: java, unit-testing, ant, junit

From the definition of the **permissions** parameter at http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html, I see:

> Settings will be ignored if fork is enabled.

However, this is causing one of my unit tests (that uses PowerMock) to fail when run through ant. Is there any way to override this? Setting fork="no" causes the jvm to run out of memory, and increasing the permgen size does not fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this can be done by specifying a security policy as a jvm argument within the ant target:

```
<jvmarg value="-Djava.security.manager" />   
<jvmarg value="-Djava.security.policy=tests/unit/security.policy" />
```

Within the **security.policy** file, we can grant permissions individually, e.g.

```
grant{
   permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "setContextClassLoader";
};
```